# Format dates to Month-Year while keeping class Date

Tags: r, date

I feel like there's a pretty simple way to do this, but I'm not finding it easily...

I am working with R to extract data from a dataset and them summarize it by a number of different characteristics. One of them is the month in which an event is scheduled / has occurred. We have the exact date of the event in the database, something like this:

```
person_id    date_visit
1            2012-05-03
2            2012-08-13
3            2012-12-12
...
```

I would like to use the `table()` function to generate a summary table that would look something like this:

```
Month    Freq
Jan 12   1
Feb 12   2
Mar 12   1
Apr 12   3
...
```

My issue is this. I've read the data in and used `as.Date()` to convert character strings to dates. I can use `format.Date()` to get the dates formatted as Jan 12, Mar 12, etc. But when you use `format.Date()`, you end up with character strings again. This means when you apply `table()` to them, they come out in alphabetical order (my current set is Aug 12, Jul 12, Jun 12, Mar 12, and so forth).

I know that in SAS, you could use a format to change the appearance of a date, while preserving it as a date (so you could still do date operators on it). Can the same thing be done using R?

My plan is to build a nice data frame through a number of steps, and then (after making sure that all the dates are converted to strings, for compatibility reasons) use `xtable()` to make a nice LaTeX output.

Here's my code at present.

```
load("temp.RData")
ds$date_visit <- as.Date(ds$date_visit,format="%Y-%m-%d")
table(format.Date(safebeat_recruiting$date_baseline,format="%b %Y"))
```

ETA: I'd prefer to just do it in Base R if I can, but if I have to I can always use an additional package.

Comment: The first thing that came to mind was to make the table first with the original date formats, and then convert them just before using xtable.

Comment: Yes, but if you do table() on the full dates, you get a summary by the individual dates. So, you wouldn't have a summary by month, but by day...hmm. I may have just pointed out a fatal flaw in my own logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`month.abb` is a constant vector in R and can be used to sort on the first three letter of the string of `names` for the table.

```
ds <- data.frame(person_id=1:3, date_visit=as.Date(c("2012-05-03", "2012-08-13", "2012-12-12")))
table(format( ds$date_visit, format="%b %Y"))
tbl <- table(format( ds$date_visit, format="%b %Y"))
tbl[order(  match(substr(names(tbl), 1,3), month.abb) )]

May 2012 Aug 2012 Dec 2012 
       1        1        1
```

With additional years you would see the "May"s all together so this would be needed:

```
 tbl[order( substr(names(tbl), 5,8),  match(substr(names(tbl), 1,3), month.abb) )]
```

Comment: Genius. Thanks! I didn't know they had a month vector already. That's awesome.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the `yearmon` class from the `zoo` package

```
require("zoo")
ds <- data.frame(person_id=1:3, date_visit=c("2012-05-03", "2012-08-13", "2012-12-12"))
ds$date_visit <- as.yearmon(ds$date_visit)
ds
  person_id date_visit
1         1   May 2012
2         2   Aug 2012
3         3   Dec 2012
```

Comment: I'd prefer to use only the base package if I can, but it's good to know about the zoo package. Thanks!